# Why does the "Navigate To" feature stops working in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have been a fan of the new "Navigate To" feature that was [released](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudio2010Released.aspx) with Visual Studio 2010 since I saw Scott Hanselman using it in one of his [presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-QrNrCT08-s).

For some unknown reason, it randomly stops working.

I hit "Ctrl + ,", type what I am looking for and then nothing happens.

It seems to wait for something and the window shows no progression in the research.

[image]

The only way I found to fix this is to restart Visual Studio and wait for the problem to happen again.

Does anyone have any idea why Visual Studio is behaving like this and how I can fix this?

Comment: Well, that quacks loudly like a bug.  Did you install the service pack yet?  Available since yesterday.

Comment: @Hans: I will try to install the service pack and update the question with the result of my tests. Thank you for telling me.

Comment: @Hans: After a couple days of testing after installing VS2010 SP1, the problem did not reappear. If you post your comment as an answer I would accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: Happens to me as well... sooo annoying.

Comment: Happening to me, too.  If I disable Resharper and restart VS, it works.  If I enable Resharper and restart VS, the problem returns.  It only happens in certain solutions.  This is not an answer.

Comment: I had this problem, got this working by closing all open files an reopen a random page!!!

Comment: @faridbekran, I tried that and it didn't help.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?  I tried everything including re-installation of Visual Studio, without success.  I have ReSharper installed on the same computer, but it's an old version for Visual Studio 2003 only (it isn't mentioned anywhere in VS 2010 options)

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by simply selecting an item from the Search Items dropdown. Once you do that, the search starts working again as expected.

Comment: I just tried your solution and it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: It's April 2012, and I still have this bug in VS2010 SPx with latest web tooling updates.  I do have CodeRush Xpress, Productivity Power Tools, and PowerCommands extensions installed.  Not sure what combination of the above is the actual culprit of such bug, but would love to get a fix for that.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working again by uninstalling ReShaper. It fixed some other things like the solution wide search aswell. I'm not so happy about the solution though...

Comment: Is everyone with Resharper seeing this problem?  Seems unlikely.

Comment: I don't have Resharper and it happens to me at random times. Restarting seems to be the only way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you're using resharper, powercommands, or productivity power tools?

I suspect the issue is related to one of those (I have the same issue), but since it's difficult to reproduce, it's hard to test that.